# C error: expected expression before ‘FILE’

Tags: file, c

Below is a section of my program code, which I found on the first answer to this forum post:
http://www.gamedev.net/topic/266856-how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-c/

Also, here are some links to material I've read but still not figured it out:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/333715-error-expected-expression-before-file/
http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/error-expected-expression-struct

```
char filename[100];
char mode[2];

bool exists(const char * filename)
{
    FILE * fp;
    if (FILE * fp = fopen(filename, mode))
    {
        fclose(fp);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

What I want to do in my whole program is simply create a file, then check if it exists and print to screen whether file creation succesful or not. It should be simple, but I get this error:

```
foo.c:35:6: error: expected expression before ‘FILE’
```

Sorry if I seem a little all over the place, please help me figure this out. If you want me to include any more data, just ask. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem

```
if (FILE * fp = fopen(filename, mode))
```

it should be

```
if ((fp = fopen(filename, mode)) != NULL)
```

you declared `fp` before this line.

That syntax is invalid, in c, but valid c++ syntax. Note that you are declaring `fp` twice so c++ compiler would complain anyway.

Comment: Yes. This is the example he took from gamedev, and it is valid C++, but not valid C.

Comment: ok I get no errors now, but i do get this warning: foo.c:35:2: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]

Comment: That's normal, you should add parentheses because you are `as the warning says` using an assignment as a truth value., updated the answer with a better way to write that.

Comment: @mee, this is because `x = y` awfully looks like `x == y`, and the latter is more common in `if` statements. The compiler is telling you that you might have mistyped it. Wrap the statement in parentheses to tell the compiler that you really want to use an assignment as a condition.

Comment: alright, ive fixed this error, but now i get a segmentation fault (core dumped) error. should i open a new question or continue here?

Comment: No, ask a new question. This one was solved, still, do you initialize `mode`? try `char mode[2] = "r";` or `fopen(filename, "r")` since if you want to check if the file exists you should try to open it in read only mode. And also, there are other ways to check if a file exists, but they could be platform specific.